# Closed form of volume of Small Retrosnub Icosicosidodecahedron $(U72)$ and Great Dirhombicosidodecahedron $(U75)$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, volume, solid-geometry

I would like to calculate the closed form of the volume of the following solids:

- $U72$ (known as *Small Retrosnub Icosicosidodecahedron*) $\approx 0.2286299526 l^3$
- $U75$ (known as *Great Dirhombicosidodecahedron*) $\approx 0.7968034087l^3$

> I tabulated the closed form of all other 73 uniform solids and of all 75 duals of uniform solids.
>
> - Some were known values
> - For some an equation was given in which one of the roots is the value of the volume
> - For others I calculated them by hand through knowledge of the coordinates of the vertices

> Unfortunately I'm having difficulty with these last two.
> It is not for research reasons or anything else, it is just out of curiosity since the values ​​of the more complex solids are not reported anywhere.

This site can be useful because it gives the coordinates of the vertices:

- [Vertices of U72](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/SmallRetrosnubIcosicosidodecahedron.txt)
- [Vertices of U75](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/GreatDirhombicosidodecahedron.txt)

Alternatively, does anyone know if these values ​​are reported somewhere?